# Problem with accumulators in prolog

Tags: prolog, accumulator

While learning Prolog, I'm trying to solve the following problem, using accumulators:

> Write a predicate addone2/ whose first argument is a list of integers, and whose second argument is the list of integers obtained by adding 1 to each integer in the first list. For  example, the query
>
> ```
>        addone([1,2,7,2],X).
> ```
>
> should give
>
> ```
>        X = [2,3,8,3].
> ```

I created the following code:

```
addone([], _).
addone([E|Tail], [R|Rs]) :-
    NewE is E+1,
    append([R|Rs], [NewE], NewRs),
    addone(Tail, NewRs).
```

But it's not working. Can someone tell me why? So, how do I use accumulators in Prolog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

anthares is correct in that you have to refine your base case. However, you are also making things very inefficiently with your `append` calls. In Prolog, it takes some time to get used to the power of unification, but for example, in this case it helps you to immediately set up your result list. Try the following:

```
addone([E|Tail], [E1|Rs]) :-
    E1 is E+1,
    addone(Tail, Rs).
```

That's really all there is to it. By immediately placing `E1` in your second argument's pattern, you have already created the first element of your result list. The remaining elements `Rs` will be created during the recursion. A very typical Prolog pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your help Frank! Didn't now about that "trick" without using list append. Also thanks to anthares for correcting my base case!

Comment: Thank you Frank! That trick is not obvious at all and very handy!

Answer (score 1):

The bottom of your recursion should be `addone([],[]).` in order NewRs to be connected with the []